# Read a constant mouse press in Python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am working with Turtle in Python. I know with onscreenclick I can read a mouse click and have the function perform whats asked.

What I want to do is have the function run while I'm holding the mouse click.

```
    def move(self):
        win.onscreenclick(self.direction)
        if self.xclick > 0 and self.yclick > 0:
            self.forward(20)
        if self.xclick < 0 and self.yclick > 0:
            self.backward(20)
            
        self.xclick = 0
        self.yclick = 0
        
    def direction(self, x, y):
        self.xclick = int(x)
        self.yclick = int(y)
```

Thats my code I am working with. The turtle object moves left and right each time I click based on the code but I want it to keep moving while I'm holding the mouse button down until I release it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onscreenclick like this:

```
def left_click():
    #your code goes here
turtle.listen()
turtle.onscreenklick(left_click,1)
```

If this doesn't work for you try using the keyboard module.

Comment: I think you forgot ```window=turtle.screen()``` then ```window.mainloop()``` at the end of the code.